# p-Sylow subgroup of ${GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $p$ be a prime. Show that $U = \left\{\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)\big\vert \ x \in \mathbb{F}_p\right\}$ is a p-Sylow subgroup of GL$_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Is $U$ a normal subgroup?

In order to show that $U$ is a p-Sylow subgroup, I have to show that it is a subgroup, has $p^r$ elements and #GL$_2(\mathbb{F}_p) = p^r \cdot m, m \in \mathbb{N}, p \nmid m, r > 0$.

$det \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right) = (1\cdot1)-(x\cdot0) = 1 \neq 0$, so $\#U = p$, as all possibilities for $x$ lead to an invertible matrix.

There are $(p^2 - 1)(p^2-p)$ elements in GL$_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. So I need somehow to show that $(p^2 - 1)(p^2-p) = pm, p \nmid m$. I tried to expand it, but didn't find a matching solution. Do you have any hint for me?

U is a normal subgroup iff it is the only p-Sylow subgroup. But how do I test for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, we can take $m = (p-1)(p^2 -1)$.

We have:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$

$= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\p-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\p-1&2\end{bmatrix} \not\in U$, so $U$ is not normal.

Alternatively, we have:

$U' = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\x&1\end{bmatrix}: x \in \Bbb F_p\right\}$ is another subgroup of order $p$, and is thus yet another $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 3):

Well $(p^2-1)(p^2-p) = p(p^2-1)(p-1)= p(p-1)(p+1)(p-1)$. As $p$ is a prime number, it does not divide $p+1$ or $p-1$. Thus $m=(p-1)^2(p+1)$ is not divisible by $p$.